# What's the equivalent of Ubuntu's apt-get command on a Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, ubuntu

I'm trying to install the Feedzirra gem to do some work with RSS feeds.  One documented issue with the installation is the need to install libcurl3-dev to address a common error in the installation process.

I came across this solution: [Feedzirra and How I Installed it](http://ruby.zigzo.com/2009/02/15/feedzirra-installation-errors/) but it's for Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3-dev
```

I'm running ruby on rails on a Mac and was hoping someone could tell me the equivalent command for my system.

Comment: If you are looking for a package manager, you could use homebrew

Comment: The [Fink project](http://finkers.wordpress.com/) provides `apt-get` for OS X. So you may want to use that. This is really [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) (or marginally on-topic as it pertains peripherally to install Ruby gems), so I recommend asking on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) instead. (Please read their FAQs and consider which would be appropriate given your question.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact parallel on mac to `apt` (switch to Linux for that), but some of the more common package names can most likely be installed from [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). So, after installing MacPorts, run:

```
sudo port install libcurl3-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

[Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) is a popular alternative to the above-suggested MacPorts.  I haven't used MacPorts but my impression from all the forum posts about the two is that Homebrew is easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

that would be [fink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fink), which uses apt and dpkg.

**note:**
due to the fact that official project website [www.finkproject.org](http://www.finkproject.org/) is often down, you can get an overview here [finkers.wordpress.com/about/](http://finkers.wordpress.com/about/).